# Why does Blender installer install 2.83 Alpha version?

Tags: installation

I've been using Blender 2.81 on windows and today decided to upgrade to the latest.  The installer from the download page says it will install version 2.83, but the version actually installed is 2.83 alpha.  I even downloaded the 2.82 installer, but it installs 2.83 Alpha too.

What's going on?  I'd like a non-alpha version because I have some add-ons that I'd like to install and they don't seem to work in 2.83 Alpha.

Comment: Hello :). Perhaps a silly question, but where exactly did you download the installers from?

Comment: From the Blender downloads page.

Comment: This is the right msi installer for 2.83: https://www.blender.org/download/Blender2.83/blender-2.83.0-windows64.msi/ For 2.82 it's this one: https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.82/blender-2.82a-windows64.msi All past releases can be accessed on [this page](https://download.blender.org/release/).

Comment: Yes, that's the one I used.  It installed the Alpha version.